# Mould in water when making preserved duck eggs

Tags: eggs

We have ducks at home and my wife has been making the Chinese delicacy 咸鸭蛋 preserved duck eggs for about 3 months now.

However in the past week the current batch of eggs has mould in the water.

The weather here is getting warmer as we have just switched to Spring. So we are guessing it might be the extra sunlight or warmth coming into our kitchen.

My wife didn't think we need to put it in the fridge, but is there a suggested temperature?

Answer (score -1):

When my mom made salted eggs, we always put it in the fridge.